# Is there a difference in meaning among 'should', 'happens to', or 'should happen to'?

Tags: conditional-constructions

What is the difference in the meaning of following sentences (I'm asking for detailed anlaysis of these sentences)

1. If it rains, I will stay at home.
2. If it should rain, I will stay at home.
3. If it should happen to rain, I will stay at home
4. If it happens to rain, I will stay at home.

   Can I say 'there is no difference in the meaning among 2 ,3 and 4 sentences ? There is no difference in the meaning and usage among 'should', 'happen to' or should happen to' together. Do they all mean 'by chance' ?

Again , i would like to know if the following sentences are grammatically correct or not:

1.If she should happen to read the newspaper, she would see your article.

2.If they should agree to come ,we would be delighted.

Source :perfect English grammar.com in Advanced conditionals Explained (pdf )

Comment: #4 should be "If it happens to rain".

Comment: Question has been Edited. Unlike previous,  This question is asking for detail analysis of question also differences between sentences with meaning

Comment: Why are we voting to close this as a duplicate of a question that has already been closed as a duplicate of this one? Won't that cause a tear in the space-time continuum?

Comment: @Rathony I cleaned it up a little bit and voted to re-open. I think one of these duplicates should be open to get more answers and this one has a higher voted answer (and more detail in the question now that it has been edited) than the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, but about what previous question ?

Comment: Yes, of course, i have been learning modals from different website, but when i don't understand and feel doubt, i tend to ask those questions in this stackoverflow websit,  i may have posted similar question in past, but i'm not gonna do that in the days to come.

Comment: You are not telling us what you understand and what you don't. Your questions are all "What is this?", "What are the differences?", "How can you tell the differences?". That's not the good way of asking a question. Be specific about what you understand and what you don't. You won't be able to get a definitive answer unless you change the way you ask a question.

Comment: I'm a bit poor in English, i don't know how to be specific, however,this has been included in help center. I did all i could to ask question in this site, but i'm yet to be good in English

Comment: Smile, Rathony; we want our newer users to feel welcome.

Comment: There is some good advice for writing questions in this answer on Meta: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/465 Don't worry about writing perfect English - we will help you fix up your question. It is important to tell us what you already know and explain why you are confused about something. That way we can write an answer that explains those things specifically instead of trying to guess what might help.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer as i have edited my question. I have asked something more in question which haven't been addressed in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

All the sentences are  real conditionals.

> If it rains ( which is possible, in the future  ), I will stay at home.

The following sentences are formal.
*Should* is used in an if-clause to talk about something which is possible but **not very likely**.

> If it *should* rain, I will stay at home.

*Should* can also be used in inversion, it adds emphasis.

> *Should* it rain, I will stay at home.

*Happen to* means *by chance* and is used in the same situation.

> If it *happens to* (note, there should be-s) rain (which is unlikely ), I will stay at home.

You can use both *should and happen to*

> If it *should happen to* rain (, I will stay at home.

. *Should, happen to and should happen to * are synonymous constructions and can be used interchangeably in the if-clause with a real conditional. *Happen to* is colloquial. 
Your additional sentences are grammatical and express  unreal situations. The meaning of should is the same as stated above.

Comment: Is  'Should' here used just like 'would ' is used in the conditional sentence ? For example: if it would rain ? Or why ? There is also' happen to ' used together with 'should', why ?

Comment: I'm confused here with different sentences structure, sometime should,  should happen to , sometime together,  various uses

Comment: Would is normally used in the **main** clause for second(unreal condition referring to present or future )
It expresses improbable, imaginary or untrue situations.
 There are situations, when *would* is used in the if-clause, such as colloquial usage,polite requests but that is another question.

Comment: What is the difference between 1. if it rains, i'll stay at home
2. If it should rain, i'll stay at home.

Comment: Again , do you mean ' should' and 'should happen to' are same?

Comment: Please reply me , I'm waiting for your response

Comment: Let's return to my answer: read the first and the second examples. If it rains (there's such a possibility in the future),I will...If it should rain (should happen to rain, happens to rain )by chance, which is possible but not very likely,  I will...

Comment: Read Advanced Grammar in Use or M. Swan Practical English Usage.

Comment: can i say 'should' and 'happen to' have the same meaning, that is 'by chanse', there is no difference between them whichever we use

Comment: Please reply me ,I'm waiting for your response

Comment: Could you please edit you answer as i have edited my questions? Please. I have asked something more in question. I'd be greatful if you'd do edit.

Comment: Unreal condition also expresses formality and indirect in those additional sentences, Am i right ?

Comment: The same rule as stated in the answer.

Comment: I have used "Should, should happen to and happen to'' in both real and unreal conditionals, so how it can be same rule ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39963/discussion-between-yubraj-sharma-and-v-v).